# Set dynamically max limit to jQuery datepicker in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, date, datepicker

In my application the max date is calculated based on some logic. The date is a JSON date. It will be used to set the max date.

To show the problem I have created a plunker link (http://plnkr.co/edit/KR2brhOXPMgZhbhafhex?p=preview).

In my example `max-date` attribute gets the JSON date

```
<input type="text" date-picker="" date-range="true" ng-model="Date" 
class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" 
ng-required="true" name="Date" ng-pattern='datePattern'
max-date="dateLimit"/>
```

In my controller I try to convert the JSON date to mm/dd/yy date string. For this I create a function `getcalculateddDate` that takes in

Evaluated my date in chrome dev tool console

[image]

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.datePattern = /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/i
    var jsonDateExample = "/Date(1522728000000)/";
    $scope.dateLimit = getCalculatedDate(jsonDateExample );

    function getCalculatedDate(date) {
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
        month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
        var day = (date.getDate() - 1).toString();
        day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
        return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    }    
});
```

I have created a directive to help me in achieving this

```
app.directive('datePicker', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        dateRange: '=',
        maxDate: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
        if (scope.dateRange !== undefined && scope.dateRange) {
            $(el).datepicker({
                maxDate: scope.maxDate,
                minDate: '-1M',
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(el).datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
});
```

Comment: There is no "JSON date". See [*Convert .NET date format into JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311264/convert-net-date-format-into-javascript-date) and [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid date: `"/Date(1522728000000)/"` (but a string) and definitely not a valid JSON (check it [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)).

What you can do is to pass to the function `getCalculatedDate` a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GpN5OKsNwjafrn4OGXoM?p=preview)). For example like this:

```
$scope.dateLimit = getCalculatedDate(new Date());
```

Or... from the value `1522728000000` (which, BTW, is not a valid date, see [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and [version of ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)) contained in the "JSON" create the date inside the `getCalculatedDate` function like this (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h0t2ZCW0MRLhH8TD9VAl?p=preview)):

```
$scope.dateLimit = getCalculatedDate("2018-10-20T03:24:00");
// ...
function getCalculatedDate(dateNum) {
    var date = new Date(dateNum);
    // ... remainder omitted
}
```

**Additional readings** (Thanks to OP, *DotNetBeginner*!)

- [Convert .NET date format into JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311264/convert-net-date-format-into-javascript-date)
- [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: this is how i get my date from mvc controller to angularjs controller. please check the screen shot i have added in the question

Comment: Well, you might need to fix that (if you're the mvc controller programmer). Otherwise, you'll have to apply some workaround. As you surely were able to check `new Date($scope.scheduleDate)` gives `Invalid Date`

Comment: Also check the link

Comment: thanks got it. i overlooked something that you mentioned

Comment: @DotNetBeginner great!, I'll add those links to the post, so future readers can find it easily.

Comment: yeah that will be helpful. Dates can be tricky at time with so many different formats